# Weird thing with tkinter Label, or list

Tags: python, tkinter

## hello I need help!

I tried to code a script what will help me with some math, but when I coded something weird happened. Something that never happened to me.
My current code is:

```py
import tkinter as tk


my_list = [] 


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('My own calculator')


entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry1.pack()


Label1 = tk.Label(root)
Label1.pack()

def Calculate(event):
    n = entry1.get()
    my_list.clear()
    try:
        Label1.config(text="")
        print("The divisors of the number are:")
        for i in range(1,int(n)+1):
            if(int(n)%i==0):
                print(i)
                
                my_list.append("\n" + str(i))
        print(*my_list)
        Label1.config(text=my_list)
    except:
        print("OOOPS")

Calculate_button = tk.Button(root,text="Calculate Divisors", command=Calculate)
Calculate_button.pack()


root.bind('<Return>', Calculate)


root.mainloop()
```

the result for every number(I used 21) shows this:
[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Yn1z.png)

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just append `str(i)` to `my_list`:

```
my_list.append(str(i))
```

And to better show the list in the label, join the list items with `', '`:

```
Label1.config(text=', '.join(my_list))
```

Comment: thank you! but there is one issue still, that's the button doesn't work.

Comment: Change `def Calculate(event)` to `def Calculate(event=None)` as callback via `command` option of button does not expect argument.